# Preventing default arrow key behavior when a UIComponent is focused?

Tags: actionscript-3, focus

I'm trying creating a text-input-like real-time tokenizer that consists of Block (shape/visual) components (extended from UIComponent) and dummy TextInputs, ordered in an HGroup component.

I.e. typing the expression "x+5" would look like this:

["x" block][TextInput]["+" block][TextInput]["5" block"][TextInput] <- cursor is here

Logically I also want that pressing left or right arrow keys moves focus between Block and TextInputs.

I overrode keyDownHandlers to do this, but it doesn't focus correctly. When I'm focused in a Block component, pressing left and right moves to the correct TextInput, but when moving from TextInput to Block it focuses to some other unrelated component in the parent application.

I tried using trace() statements, and it seems focus was being set twice, like this:

1) If a TextInput is focused initially, the focus goes correctly to the Block component on the side, then goes to an unrelated component.

2) If a Block is focused initially, the focus goes to the unrelated component, then focuses on the right TextInput.

preventDefault() and stopImmediatePropagation() did not seem to stop focus from going to the unrelated component.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!